# Synchronization java issue

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am trying to implement the Token bucket rate limiter. Below is the basic code I have written but not getting the expected result. It seems like I am missing something or I am not yet fully understood how to thread function in java. Can some one help me to look in the right direction?

```java
public class RateLimiterTokenBucket implements RateLimiter, Runnable{

    Integer capacity;
    Integer frequencyInMilliseconds;
    Integer currentCapacity;

    public RateLimiterTokenBucket(Integer frequencyInMilliseconds,Integer capacity) {
        this.frequencyInMilliseconds = frequencyInMilliseconds;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.currentCapacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean consume() {
        synchronized (currentCapacity) {
            if(currentCapacity <= 0) return false;
            --currentCapacity;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (currentCapacity) {
            OffsetDateTime t = OffsetDateTime.now();
            while(true) {
                if(OffsetDateTime.now().isAfter(t.plus(frequencyInMilliseconds, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))){
                    if(currentCapacity<capacity){
                        System.out.println("token added");
                        ++currentCapacity;
                    }
                    t=OffsetDateTime.now();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        RateLimiter rl = new RateLimiterTokenBucket(10,5);
        Thread t = new Thread((Runnable) rl);
        t.start();
        while(true){
            if(rl.consume()) {
                System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now()+" ---> true");
            }
        }
    }
```

just getting

```text
2023-04-29T19:30:54.685553+05:30 ---> true
token added
```

as output
with both threads main and t1 still running

Answer (score 2):

The entire body of your `run` method is a `synchronized` block. That practically *always* is a mistake. What is it that you don't want any other thread to be able to do until the thread is completely finished and the `run` method has returned?

Also, `synchronized(currentCapacity)` looks like a mistake because your program assigns different objects to `currentCapacity`. What does it mean when one thread is synchronized on `Integer(5)` and another thread is synchronized on `Integer(4)`? You can avoid ever making that mistake if you never write `synchronized(foo)` unless `foo` is a `final` variable.

---

Also of note: Your main thread *spins* (i.e., it burns CPU time) while awaiting the next token. That's not *always* a bad thing, but it usually *is* a bad thing if the host on which you are running does not have a CPU reserved for the exclusive use of that thread and there are other threads that are ready-to-run and waiting their turn to use a CPU.

---

P.S., Have you considered using a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) as the "bucket?" Your rate limiter could call `semaphore.availablePermits()` to find out how many tokens are in the bucket, and call `...release()` to add another token to the bucket. And, your main thread can call `semaphore.acquire()` to *wait* for the next token.